# can't access localhost:1158/em in oracle 11gR2

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

I recently installed oracle 11gR2 in windows 10 64bit, but after installation I can't access `localhost:1158/em` so i searched and found that i must run `emctl start dbconsole` but this service is already running, so please help me.